# Given a 4th degree polynomial with the first coefficient≠1 can you write it as a 4th degree polynomial with the first coeficient = 1?

Tags: polynomials

Given the general 4th degree polynomial with real coefficients
$$
ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0
$$

And knowing that the roots are $$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$$ and that the polynomial can be written as:
$$
a*(x-x_1)*(x-x_2)*(x-x_3)*(x-x_4)=0
$$

My question is: Is it possible to write the first polynomial as
$$
(x-y_1)*(x-y_2)*(x-y_3)*(x-y_4)=0 
$$
and if its possible, how would one find the roots y1,y2,y3,y4?

If its not possible all the time, when is it possible?

Edit: My idea was to use the general formula from Wolfram alpha. Apparently it gives me a different formula when the first coefficient is different than 1, but im now sure if it works.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ax%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be%3D0
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4%2Bbx%5E3%2Bcx%5E2%2Bdx%2Be%3D0

Comment: If you does the product $(x-y_1)*(x-y_2)*(x-y_3)*(x-y_4)=0$ then the lider coeficient is $1$, so i think you cannot do that.

Comment: If you want the exact same polynomial, then it is not possible (unless $a=1$) because the leading coefficients will be different.  If you mean a polynomial with the same roots, simply divide your original equation by $a$.  If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: "*gives me a different formula*" $\;-\;$ It's the same formula, just with $a$ replaced by $1\,$. Lookup [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) to see where the formulas come from.

Comment: And for the future, try to avoid using “$*$” for multiplication.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Ok, youre right. I wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible.

If you do the product $$(x−y_1)(x−y_2)(x−y_3)(x−y_4)=0$$ then the leading coefficient is $1$.